# Coded UI Test can't access focus-visable button in winRow

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, coded-ui-tests

When recording CUIT in Visual Studio 2015 (C#), I click inside a WinRow (inside a property grid-view table) which enables the ellipse [...] button control to click and open a pop-up window. However, the button is only visible when the WinRow is selected. So on playback, the WinRow loses focus between steps and the button is no longer visible to be clicked.

Does anyone know how to keep the focus inside the WinRow to be able to see/click the button?

Answer (score 0):

Well if the WinRow is defined in your UIMAp Designer file, then you should add a clik on it just before the click on the button to put again the focus on the Winrow first.

But you will have to handcode it in external cs file because any modification on the UIMap designer will be automatically removed at it first next update...

Note that a lot of recorded actions may not replay properly, mostly when you are in a dynamic behavior context, so you may have to handcode your automatisation to playback each needed actions.